# Counting occurrences of duplicates in multiples fields in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with call records, like so:

```
RouterCallKey | SequenceNumber | PeripheralCallKey | AgentID | CallDisposition  
100             1                500                 1         Handled
101             1                501                 2         Handled
102             1                502                 3         Transfer
102             2                502                 4         Handled
103             1                503                 1         Transfer
103             2                504                 2         Handled
```

I'm trying to report on occurences of a production issue. For each of these calls, the RouterCallKey will be the same (different legs of the same call), the sequence numbers will be different, the PeripheralCallKey will be the same, and the CallDisposition will be Transfer for the first leg and Handled for the second. Like so:

```
RouterCallKey | SequenceNumber | PeripheralCallKey | AgentID | CallDisposition  
102             1                502                 3         Transfer
102             2                502                 4         Handled
```

Agent 3 performed a transfer incorrectly, so we see the data like this. Calls that don't meet these criteria do not exhibit the issue (for example, RouterCallKey 103 is fine, and doesn't need to be counted).

I start by querying the table for a list of RouterCallKeys where the CallDisposition is Transfer. Then I use that list to get another list of ALL call legs that have a RouterCallKey in the first list.  Sample query, pseudo-code:

```
Select * from CallDetail
where DateTime between '07/15/2014 00:00:01' and '07/15/2014 23:59:59'
and RouterCallKey in
(select RouterCallKey from CallDetail
where DateTime between '07/15/2014 00:00:01' and '07/15/2014 23:59:59'
and AgentPeripheralNumber is not null
and CallDisposition = 'Transfer'
and RouterCallKey <> '0')
```

This is where I get lost. In the second list, I need to get a count of calls where the CallDisposition is Transfer, grouped by AgentID, where the RouterCallKeys match from leg to leg, AND the PeripheralCallKeys match from leg to leg. I can do this in Excel with `COUNTIFS` but can't figure it out in SQL, despite much searching. This table has millions of rows a day, and I'd like to get a periodic report set up to send me an email when the issue occurs so we can re-train the agent responsible for initiating the transfer. Ideally, the query results for the data above would look like this:

```
AgentID | BadCalls
3         1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm sure I'm overlooking a simple way to do this. I'm not really an SQL guy, but I was tasked with figuring this out. I'm also new to SO, though I've found many great solutions here, so if I'm doing SO wrong, please let me know :)

EDIT: I should probably add that the RouterCallKey is unique within a day, but the PeripheralCallKey can be reused several times within the same period. "102" and "502" are just examples, real Keys vary wildly. So basically, for each RouterCallKey for calls that have CallDisposition of "Transfer", look at all the calls with the same RouterCallKey, and for each of those, do the PeripheralCallKeys match? If they do, increment a count (BadCalls) for the AgentID that initiated the transfer.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Post your query that you've got so far, or set up a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm gravely misunderstanding the problem, this is likely to get you close to what you want; excuse any syntax quirks as I'm mostly writing DB2 now:

```
SELECT T.AgentID, count(*) as BadCalls
FROM CallRecords as T
INNER JOIN CallRecords as H
ON
  T.RouterCallKey = H.RouterCallKey
  AND T.PeripheralCallKey = H.PeripheralCallKey
  AND H.SequenceNumber > T.SequenceNumber
WHERE
  T.CallDisposition = 'Transfer'
  AND H.CallDisposition = 'Handled'
  AND T.SequenceNumber = 1
  AND T.AgentID <> H.AgentID
GROUP BY
  T.AgentID
```

Comment: Looks good at first glance, I'll try this tomorrow and report back. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Your answer (with some tweaking for my specific situation) got me within about 6 calls of my Excel figure for a 24-hour period.  Out of hundreds of thousands of calls, and 1600 or so with this issue, I'll call that close enough!  Thanks so much for your help!